# Update column values on some condition in R

Tags: r

```
    > ds[1:20,1:5]
   idSite idVisit         visitIp        visitorId   type
1       1    4103     8.37.230.12 0b146529434a43e3 action
2       1    4103     8.37.230.12 0b146529434a43e3 action
4       1    4100 117.212.128.163 2fda542e2cac67d4 action
5       1    4100 117.212.128.163 2fda542e2cac67d4 action
6       1    4100 117.212.128.163 2fda542e2cac67d4 action
8       1    4102  187.134.160.17 ab2413b2ed5bccc4 action
11      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action
12      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action
13      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action
14      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action
16      1    4101   5.107.224.242 fc77e4a99d153c16 action
19      1    4098  119.156.96.132 d083c7814aefc5e4 action
21      1    4097  95.221.204.238 87b98db4b05df2b0 action
23      1    4096  122.173.30.126 4386834b62126a2b action
25      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action
26      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action
27      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action
28      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action
29      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action
32      1    4041   49.35.130.191 eb8795f74c372b41 action
```

In the above dataframe I want to go from last row to first and rename the column `type` as "action1"/"action2/.."and so on but only for a specific `visitIp` as shown below

```
    > dactions[1:20,1:5]
   idSite idVisit         visitIp        visitorId    type
1       1    4103     8.37.230.12 0b146529434a43e3 action2
2       1    4103     8.37.230.12 0b146529434a43e3 action1
4       1    4100 117.212.128.163 2fda542e2cac67d4 action3
5       1    4100 117.212.128.163 2fda542e2cac67d4 action2
6       1    4100 117.212.128.163 2fda542e2cac67d4 action1
8       1    4102  187.134.160.17 ab2413b2ed5bccc4 action1
11      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action4
12      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action3
13      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action2
14      1    4099  168.235.201.23 5e8b3f87bd30cc1b action1
16      1    4101   5.107.224.242 fc77e4a99d153c16 action1
19      1    4098  119.156.96.132 d083c7814aefc5e4 action1
21      1    4097  95.221.204.238 87b98db4b05df2b0 action1
23      1    4096  122.173.30.126 4386834b62126a2b action1
25      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action5
26      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action4
27      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action3
28      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action2
29      1    4092   42.109.204.55 4744bd421d7f06b8 action1
32      1    4041   49.35.130.191 eb8795f74c372b41 action4
```

I have a code using for loop for this but it's taking considerably too much time in case of large dataframe (more than 30k rows) I want to avoid the for loop so that this can be done faster. My code is as follows

```
    #rename actions
ds$type<-as.characterds$type)
count<-0
visitedIp<-""
for(i in nrow(ds):1){
  if(ds[i,]$visitIp!=visitedIp){
    count<-1
    visitedIp<-ds[i,]$visitIp
    ds[i,]$type<-paste0(ds[i,]$type,as.character(count))
    next
  }else{
    count<-count+1
    ds[i,]$type<-paste0(ds[i,]$type,as.character(count))
  }
}
dactions<-ds
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are not using, can you please remove python tag?

Comment: Where is `visitedIp` ?

Comment: Why don't you simply use `ifelse`?

Comment: Please delete the `python` tag.

Comment: @saurav shekhar: visitedIp is a variable i've defined to store the current visitIp in the for loop

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin: if you can do this in python plz share the solution

Comment: @KaustubhVyas Either include that request explicitly in the question, show Python code, or delete the tag entirely, please.

Comment: @Posh_Pumpkin: i am not goin to delete the tag, kindly you can ignore the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a cumulative count grouped by a given variable, you would generally use the `ave()` function with the `cumsum()` function:

```
#first arg is input to cumsum (set to 1 here), second arg is grouping variable
ave(rep(1, nrow(ds)), ds$visitIp, FUN = cumsum)
```

To get a reverse counter by group, you would just reverse the grouping vector (second argument), to get the counter reversed, then reverse the result to match it back up to your data:

```
rev(ave(rep(1, nrow(ds)), rev(ds$visitIp), FUN = cumsum))
```

Comment: my focus in on the renaming the column value as shown in the example because i do further analysis on each "action1", "action2" and "action3"

Comment: @KaustubhVyas Your comment doesn't make sense. This single line of code does what you are trying to do: `ds$type <- paste0(ds$type, rev(ave(rep(1, nrow(ds)), rev(ds$visitIp), FUN = cumsum)))`. If that doesn't work, explain why.

Comment: sorry about previous comment....actually your solution is working but in my data the vistitIp is reapeating several times in a single dataframe. I want to consider only the subsequent group of IPs for this count. for example
the ip 8.37.230.12  in the above sample is repeated again in the actual dataframe. so it's counting it and renaming it as action1 and the rows shown in the sample are renamed as action2 and action3 which is not what i want.